# Android clear data when app goes to background

Tags: android, background, android-activity

I have an app(many activities). I want to clear few values like user credentials when the app goes background. How can I know when the app goes background? I tried to intercept the home button but seems like we cant do tht.If I call onPause(), it gets called every time I move from one activity to other. I searched a lot but not getting anything concrete.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways to achieve your goal one is clearing your data in onStop() state of your Activity which contains your data and the other way is(as you mention) Catching Home Press event.

for detecting Home press event you should override : `onAttachedToWindow()`

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

then clear your data on :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {

       //Put your Codes here to Clear Data 

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult with Android as there is no specific definition of an app going to the background. Detecting the home key would not be enough as there are many other events that would cause your app to lose focus.

For example, an incoming call would cause your app to "go to background" but to the user, this would not seem to be the case.

A possible way to achieve what you want would be to use the OnPause and OnResume methods of your activities to communicate with a service or a simple task in your application class. (Anything independent of your activity).

When OnPause is called, start a timer. When OnResume is called, stop the timer.

If the timer is not stopped within a specific time period then you would consider the app "in the background" and can clear the data.

Allow enough time to handle simple changes such as the incoming call example above. Perhaps a minute or two depending on your circumstances.